# How to add user from different tenant to the app I have registered in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have enabled the feature of Multi-Tenant in my application registration in my app. This is the following scree shot: [image]

Now I want to add user from different tenant to this tenant without changing their domain name. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to add user from different tenant to this tenant without
> changing their domain name. What should i do?

For this, you would need to invite that user as a guest user in your Azure Tenant. To do so, go to "Users" and then click on "New guest user".

[image]

On the next screen, simply select "Invite user" option and provide all details for the guest user. They will be sent an invitation email and once they accept it, they will be added as a guest user in your Azure Tenant. They should be sign in using their existing "Work/school account".

[image]