Is it possible to create a User (Microsoft Entra ID) for Tenant B from Tenant A?
I have a situation as follows:
I have 2 Tenants, Tenant A and Tenant B. User A belongs to Tenant A.
After User A logs into Tenant A, they make a call to the Graph API to create/edit a user for Tenant B.
I want to ask if the above situation is possible? If so, what steps need to be taken?
Currently, I don't have any direction to solve this situation. I sincerely hope for your assistance.
Thank you.

This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626804/how-to-add-user-from-different-tenant-to-the-app-i-have-registered-in-azure-ad

Yes, you can create a User (Microsoft Entra ID) for Tenant B from Tenant A User like below:
Add/Invite TenantA user as guest in TenantB:

TenantA user must accept the invite:

In TenantB assign User Administrator role to the TenantA user:

Create a Microsoft Entra ID and assign User.ReadWrite.All delegated permissions:

Make use of below endpoint to and login with TenantA user:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=TenantBAppID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&response_mode=query
&state=12345


Generate an access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:TenantBAppID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret


By using the above access token, I am able to create user in  TenantB by TenantA User:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "UserCreatedbyTenantAUser",
  "mailNickname": "test",
  "userPrincipalName": "test@xxx.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "***"
  }
}


TenantB:


Thank you for your help. I have question: Is it necessary to grant User Administrator role to user in TenantA?

No it is not necessary
